# Having issue with async/await in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, async-await

I am writing a card playing app in Xamarin Forms. As the cards are played by the computer, I want to display a played card every second. I am using this logic. It works fine for most of the the time, but often the card play speeds up. I have attached an image of the console.writeline output. At 8:20:11, the card playing speeds up to about 2 cards per seconds. This is my first attempt at using async/await. Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing the speed up?

```
    private async Task ProcessPlayMessages()
    {
        PlayMessage oPlayMessage;

        while (PlayMessageQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            oPlayMessage = (PlayMessage)PlayMessageQueue.Dequeue();
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((arg) => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    if (oPlayMessage.Type == (int)SHEnums.PlayMessageType.Card)
                    { 
                        if (oPlayMessage.Card.PlayerNumber == 3)
                        {
                            Card7.Source = GetCardSource(oPlayMessage.Card.CardKey);
                            Card7.IsVisible = true;
                        }
                        if (oPlayMessage.Card.PlayerNumber == 2)
                        {
                            Card8.Source = GetCardSource(oPlayMessage.Card.CardKey);
                            Card8.IsVisible = true;
                        }
                        if (oPlayMessage.Card.PlayerNumber == 1)
                        {
                            Card11.IsVisible = true;
                            Card11.Source = GetCardSource(oPlayMessage.Card.CardKey);
                        }
                        if (oPlayMessage.Card.PlayerNumber == 4)
                        {
                            Card9.Source = GetCardSource(oPlayMessage.Card.CardKey);
                            Card9.IsVisible = true;
                        }
                        if (oPlayMessage.Card.PlayerNumber == 5)
                        {
                            Card10.Source = GetCardSource(oPlayMessage.Card.CardKey);
                            Card10.IsVisible = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

[image: Output of console.writeline]

Comment: You can try to determine if it's the same time and only let it execute once.

Comment: Instead of Task.Delay use Timer. When you use [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0). Implementation logic may change.